# How to use multiple lists in a random order but matching each time

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops

I'm using selenium to try and input information into different elements (text boxes for price, information, etc). I'm trying to use multiple lists  (one for price, information and so forth) but keeping them in order so that the title will match the price and so forth. (Basically I'm looking to loop this program over and over so that it can keep entering the same information but will choice it in a random order but will also match. So I don't list something for a price that I want to sell it for) I'm also looping this program so it goes back to the list to re-input the information so also need it to not use the same item from the list over and over.I tried using an array but I couldn't seem to figure it out.

as an example of what I'm trying to do.

text = [shoes, motorcycle, hat, car, gold coins]
prices = [$10, $350, $5, $6500, $1450]

when I input these how can i randomize them but keep them in order with there prices? Sorry if this is confusing, I'm terrible at explaining myself.

If I use `random.choice` is just blend's them up, any idea's?? Thanks for your time to read this any input would be appreciated! Here is my code:

```
body_of_text = browser.find_element_by_class_name("Body")
prices = browser.find_element_by_class_name('Pricing')

body_of_text_list = ['This is a', 'example of ', 'text I can put in the body', 'for the pricing']
post_body = random.choice(body_of_text_list)
body_of_text.send_keys(post_body)

prices_list = ['500', '1000', '200', '850']
post_price = random.choice(prices_list)
prices.send_keys(post_price)
```

Comment: no idea what you are trying to do and where your problem is. If you want to use up the whole list in a random order, shuffle it using random.shuffle( ) and pop usedelements until list empty. You should try to [edit] somewhat more context into your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and please detail your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this - randomly choose an index which is then used to index both lists. That way you get a random index but prices and text both use the same index. Is that what you're after?

### Code:

```
body_of_text = browser.find_element_by_class_name("Body")
prices = browser.find_element_by_class_name('Pricing')

body_of_text_list = ['This is a', 'example of ', 'text I can put in the body', 'for the pricing']
prices_list = ['500', '1000', '200', '850']

i = random.choice(range(len(body_of_text_list)))

post_body = body_of_text_list[i]
body_of_text.send_keys(post_body)

post_price = prices_list[i]
prices.send_keys(post_price)
```